# Check LDAP connection (Java)

Tags: java, ldap, naming

I'm using javax naming to connect to an LDAP database.
Is there a good way to check if a connection is still valid?
I'm looking for something really efficient here because it may need to be done often.

After some web searching all I have found is a suggestion to do a quick search, is there any more lightweight way?

/mac

Comment: You don't have any visibilty over the connections. They are pooled behind the scenes. However you should not retain `Contezt` objects for long periods. Acquire them when needed and release them ASAP. The connection pool in JNDI will reduce the performance cost of this considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just assume it is still valid?  That seems the most efficient.  Encapsulate the LDAP communication in a class.  You can handle any exceptions due to a dropped connection by reconnecting and then re-performing the requested operation.

Comment: I tend to agree. The assumption is that it's valid, the *Exception* is that it's not, and should be handled as such.

Comment: Yeah I agree and that's sort of how we have it right now, but there is this framework we need to shoehorn the code into ;)
Thanks for the reply anyway, I guess maybe we can keep it like we have it now.